Difference of top 2 timestamps by group in Pandas
I have a table of users with login date and time stamps.
I am attempting to calculate the difference between each user's two most recent logins.
For example (df):



User
logints




34
2024-07-10 07:49:11.773


34
2024-07-10 07:52:11.606


34
2024-07-11 08:49:11.947


34
2024-07-11 09:49:11.758


34
2024-07-12 09:46:11.758


37
2024-07-10 08:46:11.587


37
2024-07-10 08:49:11.356


37
2024-07-09 08:49:11.744


38
2024-07-10 08:55:11.742



Desired Result:



User
logindelta




34
1 day


37
3 minutes


38
na



Here's what I have tried:
top_two_userlogins = df.groupby('User')['logints'].nlargest(2).diff()
The issue is the diff does not consistently be calculating within the groupby.
I've also tried pivoting into columns for the calculation unsuccessfully.  It seems as though there should be an operation I can run on the group.

What do you get without the diff()? That should guide you to the answer.

Without the diff I get a clean groupby with expected values.  It looks like the diff is somewhat working but not contained within the group.

Ummm, no, you get a Series that is the result of a groupby, it's no longer a groupby. See the difference here: https://trinket.io/python3/dfac7c0255

One option is to sort the dataframe by 'logints', groupby on 'User' and get the diff, then drop_duplicates by 'User':
df["logints"] = pd.to_datetime(df["logints"])
df = df.sort_values("logints")
df["logindelta"] = df.groupby("User").diff()
df = df.drop_duplicates("User", keep="last").drop(columns="logints")

   User             logindelta
6    37 0 days 00:02:59.769000
8    38                    NaT
4    34        0 days 23:57:00


This should work - thanks!

While you can use tricks with sorting and removing duplicates, that has a significant (and redundant) overhead for large sets.
I'd just use a lambda expression to apply multiple operations within a group...
out = df.groupby('User')['logints'].agg(
    lambda x: abs(x.nlargest(2).diff().max())
).reset_index(name='diff')

print(out)

Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/0e7a165628

nlargest in a groupby should be very inefficient for larger datasets, as it involves sorting and repeatedly reshaping arrays for every group.

@e-motta Every answer here will require sorting, but sorting n smaller sets is cheaper than sorting the whole set.

@e-motta I stand corrected, sorting groups is really slow in pandas, but if the data is already pre-sorted by ["User", "logints"], then using tail() in a lambda is quite cheap...  Timing Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/f6fbfd4f65
